# Mysql 'Like' search in Spring boot and hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating a search functionality in my application which uses Spring boot + Hibernate. The database is MySQL. 
I need to perform search on data on a few fields in my entity. I also want to do a partial data match, essentially what MySQL 'LIKE' does.

eg: ...

```
 WHERE name LIKE '%searchText%' OR description LIKE '%searchText%'.
```

I know I can use @Query or findByNameContaining. But this will not be very optimised as the data increases.

I used this as an example to search:

http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/23/spring-boot-and-hibernate-search-integration/

This worked fine for me for full data match. But I cannot figure out how I can utilise this for partial data match.

EDIT: adding example data and more description

example: if I have the following rows:

```
id     | name        | description                       | type

1      | sample      | this is a sample description      | Y

2      | samples     | this is a description for samples | Y

3      | not a match | this should not match             | Y

4      | not a match | this should also not match        | Y
```

Result :

```
1      | sample      | this is a sample description      | Y

2      | samples     | this is a description for samples | Y
```

So, when I search for sample, it should match the first two rows on 'sample' and 'samples', and more rows if it finds 'sample' substring in name or description.

Also, I would like to add more fields in search clause. Example: search only those rows where 'type' is 'Y'

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean for partial match .. update  you question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @scaisEdge added data sample

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Restriction.ilike` with `Restriction.or` and will get result like you want:

```
Criterion cond1= Restrictions.ilike("name","%"+searchText+"%");
Criterion cond2= Restrictions.ilike("description", "%"+searchText+"%");
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(cond1, cond2));
```